# Is there a way in EmberJS to simply specify a model on an INPUT field - - like ng-model="prop" (not via views)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to EmberJS and hate writing Views in the following manner:

```
{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="placeholder text" valueBinding="title" }}
```

Instead I would like to write something like :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="title" />
```

The second one above is from AngularJS

I've seen this:

```
<input type="text" {{bindAttr value="title"}}></input>
```

But when I change the text value, it does not update the model value (or bound value for other elements)

Is there a way in EmberJS to simply specify a model in a text field - like ng-model="..." ?

Comment: In RC3 you can do `{{input type=text value=title}}`

Comment: @milkywayjoe Thanks, it does make it more readable - but I still prefer to keep html as html. (But I also love handlebars instead of angular templates)